# How to deploy existing django application on a server?

Tags: django, web-applications, deployment, server

I have a django application and I want to deploy it on a server.
All the tutorials I found were for new applications so they don't fit to me.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is your undeployed application any different from a new one? And did you read the very detailed instructions on the Django docs site, or Google to find any one of the thousands of equally detailed tutorials?

Comment: There are tons of tutorials that show how to deploy an already built django app. If you did search well, you would have seen them.

Answer (score 2):

You sounds like a newbie for deploying the django app. **[Here](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2017/01/deply-django-with-nginx.html)** is a complete step by step tutorial to deploy existing django app using `nginx`, `virtualenv`, `gunicorn`. If you find the textual instruction difficult to follow then you can watch this **[video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jN9iPaQzZbQ)** as well.

Hope this helps.